# Basic loop over directories

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop through folders in a directory and add them to a dictionary, at the moment it seems to be only adding the last one. Hoping someone can shed some light or show maybe a better method.

```
project_directory = 'C:/Users/rudyd/Desktop/music_projects'

project_dict = {
    'title' : [],
    'year' : []
} 

# List of file names
files = os.listdir(project_directory)

#     Loop to add directory names to project_dict[title]
for index in range(len(files)):
    project_dict['title'] = files[index]



print(project_dict)

# Current output = {'title': 'xmas eve piano1 Project', 'year': []} this is the last
file in the list
```

Comment: You're overwriting the same value over and over. Try `project_dict['title'].append(files[index])`

Comment: @chris-j so obvious thank you

Comment: If you're adding them all unconditionally, why not just assign it: `project_dict['title'] = files`?